# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am facing the following error while trying to run my service. Can someone please help me out in this ? I am not sure if it is a spring version mismatch issue. I use the same version as defined in my **pom.xml**.

**Error Trace:**

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:259)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:158)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4641)
```

Herewith I am sharing my **pom.xml** file

```
 <properties>

    <org.springframework.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

    <org.springframework.batch>4.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.batch>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring dependency-->

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

      <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>

      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.batch}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependency ends-->
      </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have this setter `setRole()` in your Bean definition class?

Comment: Post your pom.xml

Comment: The same problem occurred here:: [springboot get error when server starting in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382470/)... but there's no resolution posted.  ".Jar version conflict" is definitely a good guess; posting your pom.xml would definitely be useful.  ALSO: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879662/421195) - define property `<spring.version>` in your pom.xml, then use it for *ALL* your Spring dependencies in the pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems version mismatch issue, Check if following combination work for you:

```
<properties> 
 <org.springframework.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
 <org.springframework.batch>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.batch> 
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

By Changing Spring version to 5.0.3 and spring batch to 4.0.0, the service started successfully.

Comment: I think it's same what I have mentioned in my answer.